# Dictionary view objects vs sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, view, set

I have been reading about these dictionary view objects that are returned by the likes of `dict.keys()`, including the posts on here about the subject. I understand they act as windows to the dictionary's contents without storing a copy of said contents explicitly and in so are more efficient than dynamically updating a list of keys. I also found they are containers (allow use of `in` operator) but are **not** sequences (not indexable), although they **are** iterable.

Overall this sounds to me like a `set`, since they have access to the dictionary's hash table they even offer the use of `set`-like operations like intersection/difference. One difference I can think of is that a `set`, while mutable like these view objects, can only store immutable (and therefore hashable) objects.

However, since a dictionary *value* doesn't have to be immutable, the `values` and `items` view objects are essentially `set`s with mutable contents, expectedly **not** supportive of `set`-like operations (subtraction/intersection). This makes me sceptical of considering these view objects as "a `set` with a reference to the dictionary".

**My question is:** are these view objects entirely different to sets but happen to have similar properties? Or are they implemented using sets? Any other major differences between the two? And most importantly - can it be damaging to consider them as "basically `set`s"?

Comment: "a dictionary value doesn't have to be immutable", but a dictionary key has to (well, it needs to be hashable, like with sets). It doesn't really matter how exactly are these views implemented, like you say they work as iterable containers, and that's all you need to know. The actual implementation could in theory change from one version of Python to the next. You can consider them as immutable sets if you want (the documentation of `.keys()` says it is a "set-like object"), in that they offer the same operations (although not necessarily the same complexity for each of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit point of your comparison is that `dict.keys()` and `set` elements can't have duplicates. However, the set-like Dictionary view obtained from the keys still retains order, while the set does not.

**Duplicate dictionary keys:**

> [If a key occurs more than once, the last value for that key becomes the corresponding value in the new dictionary.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

**Duplicate set elements:**

> [A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

From the above, `set`s are unordered while in the current Python version dictionaries maintain insertion order:

> [Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

Because dictionaries have an insertion order they can be reversed, while such operation in a set would be meaningless:

> [Dictionaries and dictionary views are reversible.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

Finally, a `set` can be altered, deleted and inserted from. A Dictionary view object only allows looking at contents, not changing them.

> My question is, are these view objects entirely different to sets but happen to have similar properties? Or are they implemented using sets?

The documentation makes no claim about implementation details.

> Any other major differences between the two?

The documentations state the difference between "Keys views" and "items view" or "values views".

> [***Keys views*** are set-like (...)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)
>
> [If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and hashable, then the ***items view*** is also set-like.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)
>
> [(***Values views*** are not treated as set-like (...))](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)